# can one prove the fundamental theorem of algebra using that symmetric real matrices have real eigenvalues

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, real-numbers

Without applying the fundamental theorem of algebra, one can prove that any symmetric $A\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ has a real eigenvalue. [indeed, a local maximum of $x^tAx$ on the unit sphere has to be a real eigenvector.] I was wondering if one could use this fact as the basis for proving that $\mathbf{C}$ is algebraically closed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: crossposted to MO on March 12, 2022: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418020/